# Install php imagick for Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagick

I tried to install `imagick` using `pecl` on OSX and PHP 7.2.

If I run `php -i | grep -i imagick` I get following output:

```
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.3
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 7.0.7-28 Q16 x86_64 2018-03-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 7.0.7-28 Q16 x86_64 2018-03-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
```

However if I try to use it in a Laravel controller I get

> "Class 'Imagick' not found"

This is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Imagick;

class OrderImageController extends Controller
{
    public function proofImage(Request $request) {
        $image = new Imagick($request->image);
    }
}
```

If I take a look in my `php.ini` file `extension=imagick.so` is there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you restarted php-fpm?

Comment: I am using valet and did a `valet restart`... PHP and nginx restarts then. php-fpm should be included right?

Comment: I think you should install php-imagick package too, no only imagick.

Comment: @Laerte You mean not only imagemagick? Imagick is the php extension for imagemagick - I think that should be okay.

Comment: @MangoD did you add echo "extension = imagick.so"> /etc/php.d/imagick.ini to php.ini?

Comment: It auto added the extension to first line in php.ini which looks like this `extension="imagick.so"`

Comment: @MangoD Did you manage to solve this?